# How to find the CPU load of the remote system

Tags: java, jmx, multicore

Hi am developing an load balancing algorithm in java. In my system there will be one master node and n number of slave nodes. The mater node will distribute the receiving query to ones of its slave node. But before distributing the query to one of its slave node, I want to measure the current load in the slave node in order to check whether the particular slave node is capable of processing the request. And also i can keep track of which node is overloaded and which one is least loaded.

Can any one please tell me, Is there any built in functions in java (by including some .jar file) to find the load of the slave nodes..? Whether i can use  JMX to do it..?

Answer (score 1):

I think that OperatingSystemMXBean's [getSystemLoadAverage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemLoadAverage%28%29) is what you need.

For info on remote accessing this JMX bean please read [Remote Monitoring and Management](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html#remote) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Since i didnt used JMX before i have few simple question. The getSystemLoadAverage() is used to find out the current load of the node. But how to find out whether the slave node is capable of processing the incoming request without get overloaded.

Comment: I think if we can able to find out, the maximum load that the slave node support and the processing time of the incoming request, we can derive the mathematical equation to find our need.. So please tell me is it possible to find out the maximum load that can be supported by the node and how much load that incoming request will inject on the node..?

Comment: These are very interesting questions indeed and they deserve a separate thread to be started.